Copying a value of the formula field to a text field using flow
I have requirement to capture the value of a formula field (Field A) to number field (Field B) in the Opportunity. The value of the formula field is a combination of numbers/price from a Opportunity Line Item.
So my requirement is to copy the formula value to Field B when a value appears in Field A.
I tried creating flow but the entry condition is only when the record is created or updated which is not my actual criteria and it should be whenever the formula field value is auto changed my flow should update the number field.
Can someone guide me with a solution.

Flows (and triggers, for that matter) can only run when a record undergoes a save operation. Formula recalculation does not cause a save operation to begin.
You're going to need to base your entry criteria on one (or more) field(s) that lead to the formula evaluating to a new value rather than basing it on the formula field directly.
If your formula only uses other calculated values, like IF(MOD(DAY(TODAY()), 2) = 0, 'Red', 'Blue'), then you're mostly out of luck.

As per the answer to this question, formula fields get re-calculated at demand.
So for your use case, Field A will get calculated when the Opportunity Line Item is changed/updated.
You will be able to create a flow that triggers when an Opportunity Line Item is updated.
Unfortunately roll-up summary fields get calculated after a flow has run, so the flow cannot run immediately. You will have to add a scheduled path in the record triggered flow. I created a POC using the Quote and Quote Line Item Objects:

High level of operation is:

Flow triggers when Quote Line Item is updated
Waits 1 minute
Gets the Quote record
Copies Field A's value across to Field B

Here are screenshots of just after the Quote Line Item was updated:

And 1 minute later after the flow has run:

The user is able to edit Field B's value if/when required.
Some considerations

With the wait path, the flow waits 1 minute after LastModifiedDate. If you want it to run 1 minute after the Quote Line Item is created, you might need to create another flow that only runs when a record is created
This flow will update Field B every time a related Quote Line Item is updated. If you do not want the flow to update the field again after a user has made a change, then you will need to add some additional logic
If the 1 minute wait for the value of Field A to be copied over to Field B is not feasible, you can make the flow run asynchronously, but then you will need to specify an entry criteria (e.g. Quantity is changed) otherwise you won't be able to activate the flow

Good luck!

Hi Adriaan, the challenge here is Field B should be an editable field and It should copy the value of field A and it should be editable by the opporutnity owner. So field A is a formula (Currency rollup summary field (Opportunity line item)+ fixed percentage from opportunity. Field B is a discounted total price field which should copy the initial value from field A and should be editable.

@Anonymous123 I updated my answer based on the additional info you provided. Thanks
